# Should I send a follow up to lab after applying for a position through university job board?

Tags: job-search

I applied for a position through a university's job board, but the lab the position it's through has a separate site with a contact name listed if I'm interested in joining or learning more about the lab. I'm wondering if I should send an email to this person, nothing long just a quick 'Hey I applied to this position, please let me know if you need anything additional'? If so, how long should I wait (I applied about a week ago), and should I CC the PI? The application is listed as being under review, idk if that changes anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything wrong with a followup like that after a week. You may not get a reply and if not, just wait for something official to come to you.

If there is a listed contact, I'd leave it at that without also contacting the PI.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll wait a few more days and then reply. Thank you!